# Python PyPDF2 get unwanted characters from PDF document using Google Colab

Tags: python, pdf, text, pypdf

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF file using Python.
I'm using the PyPDF2 package (version 1.27.12)
I run the following code:

```py
import PyPDF2 as P2

Casos = 0
while Casos < registros:
  PDFfile= open(archivo.iloc[Casos,3], 'rb')
  pdfread=P2.PdfFileReader(PDFfile)

  i=0
  while i<pdfread.getNumPages():
    pageinfo=pdfread.getPage(i)
    Origen.append(archivo.iloc[Casos,1])
    Info.append(pageinfo.extractText())
    #print(i)
    i=i+1
  
  #print(i)
  Casos = Casos + 1
```

The code worked well before, however, right now, I get the following output which is different from that included in the PDF document:

> ['M idió efe ctiv am ente el impacto  de X e n lam arca de la em presa. Intro dujo t ácticas inno v ado ras para']

The correct text is:

> Midió efectivamente el impacto de X en la marca de la empresa. Introdujo tácticas innovadoras para

Wonder to know if any update or code modification is required, any observation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `pypdf` instead. Your code needs to be adjusted like this:

https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
for page in reader.pages:
    print(page.extract_text())
```